# Wave function collapse for experimental quantum state preparation

Tags: quantum-entanglement, experimental-technique, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-states

Has the John von Neumann projection, or the wave function collapse, been used in the experimental preparation of quantum states? As an illustration, for a pair of EPR-type entangled 2-level atoms

$$|\psi_{12}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle_1|+\rangle_2 + |-\rangle_1|-\rangle_2)$$

or equivalently $|\psi_{12}\rangle$ can be re-written as

$$|\psi_{12}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|p\rangle_1|p\rangle_2 + |q\rangle_1|q\rangle_2)$$

where

$$|p\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle)$$
$$|q\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle - |-\rangle)$$

By choosing to measure atom 1 in states {$|+\rangle_1, |-\rangle_1$}, atom 2 would be prepared in either state $|+\rangle_2$, or state $|-\rangle_2$.

By choosing to measure atom 1 in states {$|p\rangle_1, |q\rangle_1$}, atom 2 would be prepared in either state $|p\rangle_2$, or state $|q\rangle_2$.

Has this type of experimental preparation of quantum states been realized in the lab?

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking if post-selection of measurement outcomes is ever used to prepare the system for subsequent measurements? Or are you asking more specifically if some experiments deliberately prepare an entangled state first and then apply another measurement to finish preparing the state for subsequent measurements?

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly: Honestly I am not fully familiar with the exact meaning of the post-selection of measurement outcomes. If that means something like photon polarizer type of "measurement" for projecting an individual photon's polarization state, that is not what I am looking for. Yes, the EPR type of entanglement experiment followed by the measurement to prepare the quantum states is what I am asking about. I appreciate your clarification.